# Python pandas: for each unique value in a column, find a minimum value in another column and subtract it from the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Alex', 'Alex', 'Alex', 'Eva', 'Eva', 'Eva'],
                   'Time': [30, 40, 60, 35, 55, 57]})
```

I want to create a column which will say how much the time differs from the person's lowest time:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Alex', 'Alex', 'Alex', 'Eva', 'Eva', 'Eva'],
                   'Time': [30, 40, 60, 35, 55, 57],
                   'Difference': [0, 10, 30, 0, 20, 22})
```

I have tried groupby() but I must be doing it wrong. What is the best way to do this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `Time` minus [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) 'min' to get difference between the current time value and the minimum time value per group:

```
df['Difference'] = df['Time'] - df.groupby('Person')['Time'].transform('min')
```

`df`:

```
  Person  Time  Difference
0   Alex    30           0
1   Alex    40          10
2   Alex    60          30
3    Eva    35           0
4    Eva    55          20
5    Eva    57          22
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime `apply` is more easy to understand

```
df.groupby('Person')['Difference'].apply(lambda x : x-x.min())
Out[236]: 
0     0
1    10
2    30
3     0
4    20
5    22
Name: Difference, dtype: int64
```